# How to resolve Microsoft Access Error 3043

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

My company uses a shared MS Access database, with a back end stored on a server and a front end copied onto users desktops.

Recently, our IT department moved us to a new server without giving us any notice, and now our database keeps crashing.

Every 20-40 minutes, users get an error message that says:

> Error 3043 Your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.

If they close and reopen, it does work. However, I'd like to stop this from happening, since it typically happens when they are in the middle of something and have to re-do everything.

I've already spoken with our IT consultants and they see no issue with our server/network, nor do they know anything about Access and therefore are no help.

Does anyone have any experience with this or have any ideas that may help me repair my database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ugh, welcome to hell. Is the old server still there? -- Error 3043 may become a minor nuisance compared to the backend db corruption you may face, if network interruptions happen during write operations.

Comment: @Andre no unfortunately the old server is gone. And I cannot tell if the error message is happening because users have a faulty connection to our shared drives that goes in and out for a split second, or if it is something I have to do in the back end of my database.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some thoughts:

It sounds very much like (short) network interruptions. MS Access doesn't like these **at all**, in particular it doesn't recover from a broken connection (even if very short) until you restart the frontend.

Network interruptions during **write operations** on Access backends are the prime cause of backend database corruption. Consider yourself lucky if you haven't experienced that yet. But you should backup and Compact&Repair the backend often (!) .

You can prevent backend corruptions by moving the backend to a **server database**, e.g. SQL Server Express (free). Errors will still occur ("ODBC call failed" instead of error 3043), but they will only affect the frontends.

You can probably work around all errors by changing the frontend from bound forms to **unbound forms**. This is a major undertaking.

I don't think there is anything you can do with the backend to prevent the errors.

If this database has value to your company, and IT says there is no problem, I suggest you escalate the problem to someone who can make IT look closer into the issue.
(*How* to do so would be a separate question, perhaps on SuperUser.)